# Ajuda com Action Edit e Delete retornando nulo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mas estou com um problema nas Actions Edit e Delete. Já olhei o código diversas vezes, mas ao chamar as actions citadas apresenta o seguinte erro:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter ‘id’ of
>   non-nullable type ‘System.Int32′ for method
>   ‘System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)’ in
>   ‘appXXX.Presentation.Controllers.XXXController’. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter.

Nome do parâmetro: parameters

O que estou observando é que, por algum motivo que ainda não consegui identificar, o parametro “id” nas actions citadas está retornando nulo. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Vou postar o código abaixo resumido e adaptado:

Na Camada de DOMAIN:

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();        
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Save();
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Dispose();
}

public interface IServiceBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Save();
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Dispose();
}

public class ServiceBase<TEntity> : IDisposable, IServiceBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IRepositoryBase<TEntity> _repository;

    public ServiceBase(IRepositoryBase<TEntity> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _repository.Delete(entity);
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return _repository.GetById(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Na Camada de INFRA:

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IDisposable, IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected AppContext context = new AppContext();

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }        

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Na Camada de APPLICATION:

```
public interface IAppServiceBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Save();
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Dispose();
}

public class AppServiceBase<TEntity> : IDisposable, IAppServiceBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IServiceBase<TEntity> _serviceBase;

    public AppServiceBase(IServiceBase<TEntity> serviceBase)
    {
        _serviceBase = serviceBase;
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _serviceBase.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _serviceBase.Delete(entity);
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return _serviceBase.GetById(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _serviceBase.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Na Camada de APRESENTAÇÃO (CONTROLLER):

```
public class BankController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBankAppService _bankApp;

    public BankController(IBankAppService bankApp)
    {
        _bankApp = bankApp;
    }

    // GET: Bank
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var bankViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Bank>, IEnumerable<BankViewModel>>(_bankApp.GetAll());
        return View(bankViewModel);
    }

    // GET: Bank/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        var bankDomain = _bankApp.GetById(id);
        var bankViewModel = Mapper.Map<Bank, BankViewModel>(bankDomain);

        return View(bankViewModel);
    }

    //POST: Bank/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(BankViewModel _bank)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var bankDomain = Mapper.Map<BankViewModel, Bank>(_bank);
            _bankApp.Update(bankDomain);
            _bankApp.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(_bank);
    }


    // GET: Bank/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var bankDomain = _bankApp.GetById(id);
        var bankViewModel = Mapper.Map<Bank, BankViewModel>(bankDomain);

        return View(bankViewModel);
    }

    // POST: Bank/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var bankDomain = _bankApp.GetById(id);
        _bankApp.Delete(bankDomain);
        _bankApp.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Como podem ver o código é um repositório genérico e alguns métodos não postei para diminuir o tamanho. Já fiz de várias formas baseados em exemplos na internet e projetos que baixei, mas aí na execução, quando clica no no item (uma View do tipo List), a Action Edit não é chamada pq o id retorna nulo.

A Action de Create funciona e a função GetAll() tbm. O problema mesmo é com o Edit e consequentemente com o Delete tbm. Não consigo perceber o que tem de errado.

Comment: Poste sua `View` Edit, ou verifique se ela possui `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)`.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação. Realmente estava faltam em minha View pegar @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id).

Answer (score 1):

Dá uma olhada na sua `view`, quando vc clica no botão o campo `id` está indo nulo, provavelmente porque não tem um `input name="id"` na sua `view`. Ou se tem está com o valor nulo.
Você pode mudar também o `public ActionResult Edit(int id)` para `public ActionResult Edit(int? id)`, que ai aceitará valores nulos. Mas como é para edição, acho que você precisa mesmo passar o valor no id.
Qualquer coisa posta sua `view` também.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação. Realmente estava faltam em minha View pegar @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id).